# Как обработать ситуацию, когда не получается подгрузить данные с сервера?

Tags: android

Подгружаю данные с сервера порциями. Новые порции загружаются при прокрутке экрана. Подгружаю с помощью `AsyncTask`.  
Во время подгрузки, внизу экрана появляетя `progressBar` и `TextView "loaading.."`  
Хотел обработать ситуацию, когда не получается подгрузить данные - в этом случае внизу должно появляться сообщение "`failed to load data`" и появляться кнопка "`try again`".  
Вот `layout`:

```
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<!-- Список -->

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffffff" />

<!-- Панель для прогресс-бара и для проверки подгрузки данных-->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="42dip"
        android:layout_height="42dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/try_again_button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Try again">
    </Button>
 </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Как реализовать чередование `progressBar` и кнопки для повторной загрузки?

Comment: @StasOn, подправьте, пожалуйста, название вашего вопроса - сделайте его более специфичным, чем просто "Как реализовать?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> да примерно так и делаю. Вот только теперь проблема в том, чтобы кнопка была невидима. Добавил android:visibility="invisible" для кнопки, но не сильно помогло - теперь, пока все нормально, внизу просто белая полоса остается под тот layout, в котором должна быть кнопка

Можешь ещё ставить параметр GONE,тогда вьюшка как бы удаляется из разметки,и соответственно остальные элементы изменятся соответсвуеще так как бы первой и вовсе не было.То есть полосе(лайоту)ставить Gone,тогда это полса пропадает и лист вью растягивается до низа экрана,а как загрузка,опять visible и лист вью поднимится а внизу появится полоса

Answer (score 2):

Допустим у тебя есть функция, которая качает данные с сервера и возвращает какой нибудь **ArrayList<>**. Делает она это все в **doInBackground() AsyncTask`a**.

Если интернет отвалился, то сделай чтобы она возвращала **null**.

В **onPostExecute** я бы сделал проверку на **result == null** - да, показываем кнопку, нет - добавляем данные в адаптер

Comment: да примерно так и делаю. Вот только теперь проблема в том, чтобы кнопка была невидима. Добавил android:visibility="invisible" для кнопки, но не сильно помогло - теперь, пока все нормально, внизу просто белая полоса остается под тот layout, в котором должна быть кнопка

Comment: как написали ниже, используй visibility = "gone"

Comment: @Роман Захаров, а как сделать так, чтобы, если все-таки так получилось, что не удалось подгрузить данные и это проверилось в onPostExecute, то при нажатии на кнопку снова повторялся метод загрузки данных?